# Node.js read post data from Express with Socket.io and Http

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node.js server with Express and Socket.io.
In The Socket.io docs i found this example code for host server.

My problem is now the next:
I cant read Post data from the requests.

There is a request:

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://127.0.0.1:4444/login",
                data: {
                    da: 'a'  
                },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);

                },
                failure: function(errMsg) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
```

And this is the server:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
server.listen(4444);

var database = require('./database.js');
database.methods.connect(); 


// Add headers
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8080');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});

app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

I tried a lot of thinks. For example: bodyParser.json(), bodyParser.urlencoded

But this express is run with require("http");

How can i read the body from the request?
I hope someone can help me!
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the Express body-parser middleware, something like this:

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
server.listen(4444);

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json 
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(function (req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
  res.write('you posted:\n')
  res.end(JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2))
})
```

Comment: But how can i add the `var io = require('socket.io')`  if i do not use `var server = require('http').Server(app);` ?

Comment: For so long i couldn't make that work because i was using the IO before the app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })) . Everything is OK now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You must use `body-parser` for express.
Documentation is [here](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser)

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
```

Comment: I tried it before create this question. SyntaxError: Unexpected token d  at parse

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token d                                                                                                             
    at parse (c:...\www\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:83:15)

Comment: That error means there is something wrong with your json syntax.

Comment: Try to remove content-type from ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security